# Postgres: error connecting to server "An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket."

Tags: database, localhost, postgresql-9.2

I'm using Windows, trying to get my database working so I can create a superuser on my localhost.

I successfully installed Postgres 9.2.1, but when I try to connect to the server I get:

```
Error connecting to the server: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.
```

With this in the error log:

```
PDT LOG:  incomplete startup packet
PDT WARNING:  pgstat wait timeout
LOG:  could not receive data from client: An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.
```

I completely uninstalled my antivirus and made sure Windows Firewall is turned off.

My server properties are default and postgresql.conf matches them:

```
Hostname: localhost
Port: 5432
```

I am stumped how to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have uninstalled your AV, according to Microsoft, you may have to reset your TCP/IP configuration using the information in [KB299357](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299357).

The article tells you to run the command

```
netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt
```

which will reset the values of two registry keys

```
SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\ 
SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DHCP\Parameters\
```